# How do I compare values from one datetime index to a range of other other datetime indexes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, stock, quantitative-finance

I am using pandas and mplfinance to work with a stock market data set. How can I compare the current index to the previous(x) indexes?

For example I want to find a divergence between the current price and an indicator I am using.  (Divergence is when the price is moving lower than the lowest value ‘x’ periods ago and the indicator sharing the same xaxis is not lower than the lowest value ‘x’ periods ago. X being a range of period, in this case a range of datetime indexes).

In order to do that I need to look backwards at the prior data to see if the current value of price is lower than the lowest value in the previous 15 periods. If true, I would need to check if the current value in the indicator is higher than the lowest value in the previous 15 days.

I can write a long hand version of this but it’s really not efficient to rewrite it if I want to use a different time frame or indicator.

This is the long form I managed to slap together:

```
df[‘bullDiverg’] = np.where( df.close <
((df.close.shift(1) & df.close.shift(2) & df.close.shift(3) & df.close.shift(4) & df.close.shift(5) & df.close.shift(6) &
df.close.shift(7) & df.close.shift(8) & df.close.shift(9) & df.close.shift(10) & df.close.shift(11) & df.close.shift(12) & df.close.shift(13) & df.close.shift(14) & df.close.shift(15))
& 
(df.macd.shift >
(df.macd.shift(1) & df.macd.shift(2) & df.macd.shift(3) & df.macd.shift(4) & df.macd.shift(5) & df.macd.shift(6) &
df.macd.shift(7) & df.macd.shift(8) & df.macd.shift(9) & df.macd.shift(10) & df.macd.shift(11) & df.macd.shift(12) & df.macd.shift(13) & df.macd.shift(14) & df.macd.shift(15))),1,0 )
```

A function where I enter the Datetime df price and indicator Values that creates the bullish divergences Col so I can add it to my existing data would be ideal but just a more efficient way to write what I did above would be appreciated.

Comment: Use [`pd.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it’s way less code to write! Now my next issue how can I shorten the look back period when the look back goes further back than the 52wk high. That prevents some divergences from being found. For example there is a sharpe sell off 4 days removed from a 52 week high where a divergence shows up but the divergence look back period is 10 days and w/in that 10 days the min value is lower than where the post 52 wk high occurred so it won’t show up. I’m trying to find a way to compare indexes from current to 52wk high and indexes for look back window to 52wk high. Any ideas?

Comment: @spaceJax It's not clear to me what you asking regarding "shorten the look back period when the look back goes further back than the 52wk high".  Can you provide a specific example calculation?